# Export entire database as csv file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to export entire database as csv file in codeigniter.I exported single table data as csv file in codeigniter successfully.But how to export entire database as csv file?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot export a whole database in a single CSV file. That makes no sense.

A CSV file has the concept of rows and columns, seperated by something, eg a comma.
Then follows the data, also seperated by a comma.
Each line in the file represents a row in a table.

Now, how to format that if you have more than 1 table in your database?

I once wrote a script that produces a csv file for each individual table in csv format, and zipped them together inb PHP.

But still, a normal export is prefered, because that will also contain foreign keys, primary keys, and whatever it was you added to the database.